# replacing broken outside tap handle

Tags: plumbing-fixture, hose

I have this outside hose tap, the handle arms have broken off at some in the past. Is fixing it as simple as undoing the screw and putting a new handle on? are there any gotchas to be wary off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing it **might** be as simple as removing the screw and handle and getting a replacement from the hardware or plumbing shop.

On the other hand, there are hundreds (thousands?) of manufacturers of hose faucets (also called *hose bibs*, *spigots*, *hose pipe taps*, etc.) and the stem to which the handle attaches does not have a standard size or connection method. It may be splined, it may be square, it could be various sizes.

If you don't have an easy time with a replacement handle, replacing the valve is fairly simple and this site has Helpful People to lead you through it (hint- you will need to shut off the water supply to that water line).

[image][image]